# previous row id shows in next two rows in parent column serially in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My table is:

```
SELECT id, name FROM category
```

table data shows

```
id | name
---| ----
1  | John
2  | Jimy
3  | James
4  | Phil
5  | Sayed
6  | Doe
7  | Warkes
8  | Ryan
9  | Tim
10 | Joe
```

I want like this

```
id | name   | parent_id
---| ------ | ------
1  | John   |     0
2  | Jimy   |     1
3  | James  |     1
4  | Phil   |     2
5  | Sayed  |     2
6  | Doe    |     3
7  | Warkes |     3
8  | Ryan   |     4
9  | Tim    |     4
10 | Joe    |     5
```

I want first **`parent_id`** is always **`0`** in first row and **`first row id`** shows in **`2nd`** and **`3rd`** rows **`parent_id`** column.

**`Second row id`** shows in **`4th`** and **`5th`** rows in **`parent_id`** column. It will continue serially.

if category table id start from 4 then it will show like this

```
id   | name    | parent_id
---- | ------- | --------
4    | Phil    |     0
5    | Sayed   |     4
6    | Doe     |     4
7    | Warkes  |     5
8    | Ryan    |     5
9    | Tim     |     6
```

I have only **`category table`** no other **`parent table`**.

Comment: you can create an extra row in your table called parent_id and save the id that corresponds to each parent

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: `parent_id` will show dynamic and it will depend on `category` table id. MySQL version is 5.6.43

Answer (score 0):

If your IDs are always incremented by 1 with no gaps, you can mock the `parent_id` value using the FLOOR function:

```
SELECT id, name, FLOOR(id / 2) as parent_id FROM category;
```

But a cleaner and more robust option would be to save the `parent_id` along with the entries (or in a separate related table) so your query would select the additional column like:

```
SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM category2;
```

or

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, p.parent_id FROM category c JOIN parents p ON p.id = c.id;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c74821/1 for working examples.

Comment: it works perfectly when `category` table `id is serialized` and `parent_id` value using the `FLOOR function`. But when category table `id is not serialized`, so what can I do? I have only `category` table no others table like `parents` or `category2`.

Comment: If category table id start from 4 then shows like this

`id   | name      | parent_id`
`----- | ------------ | ------------`
`4     | Phil         |     0`
`5     | Sayed     |     4`
`6     | Doe         |     4`
`7     | Warkes   |     5`
`8     | Ryan      |      5`
`9     | Tim         |     6`

Comment: Then you'll need to either create a second table to store the `parent_id`s or add a column to your existing table to store `parent_id`s. Both of these methods are shown at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c74821/1